# 2: Task failed with an exception

Tags: android, flutter, build

```
lib/data/repositories/Auth/authRepository.dart:7:1: Error: 'AuthProvider' is imported from both 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' and 'package:news/cubits/Auth/authCubit.dart'.
import 'package:news/cubits/Auth/authCubit.dart';
^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/data/repositories/Auth/authRemoteDataSource.dart:15:1: Error: 'AuthProvider' is imported from both 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' and 'package:news/cubits/Auth/authCubit.dart'.
import 'package:news/cubits/Auth/authCubit.dart';
^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/data/repositories/Auth/authRepository.dart:69:28: Error: 'AuthProvider' is imported from both 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' and 'package:news/cubits/Auth/authCubit.dart'.
      if ((authProvider == AuthProvider.email && !user.emailVerified)) {
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/ui/screens/auth/VerifyOtpScreen.dart:245:84: Error: 'AuthProvider' is imported from both 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' and 'package:news/cubits/Auth/authCubit.dart'.
                  context.read<SocialSignUpCubit>().socialSignUpUser(authProvider: AuthProvider.mobile, verifiedId: widget.verifyId, otp: otp, context: context);
                                                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/ui/screens/auth/loginScreen.dart:319:145: Error: 'AuthProvider' is imported from both 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' and 'package:news/cubits/Auth/authCubit.dart'.
                            context.read<SocialSignUpCubit>().socialSignUpUser(email: emailC!.text.trim(), password: passC!.text, authProvider: AuthProvider.email, context: context);
                                                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/ui/screens/auth/loginScreen.dart:438:84: Error: 'AuthProvider' is imported from both 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' and 'package:news/cubits/Auth/authCubit.dart'.
                  context.read<SocialSignUpCubit>().socialSignUpUser(authProvider: AuthProvider.gmail, context: context);
                                                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/ui/screens/auth/loginScreen.dart:451:86: Error: 'AuthProvider' is imported from both 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' and 'package:news/cubits/Auth/authCubit.dart'.
                    context.read<SocialSignUpCubit>().socialSignUpUser(authProvider: AuthProvider.fb, context: context);
                                                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/ui/screens/auth/loginScreen.dart:464:86: Error: 'AuthProvider' is imported from both 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' and 'package:news/cubits/Auth/authCubit.dart'.
                    context.read<SocialSignUpCubit>().socialSignUpUser(authProvider: AuthProvider.apple, context: context);
                                                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/data/repositories/Auth/authRemoteDataSource.dart:119:14: Error: Not a constant expression.
        case AuthProvider.gmail:
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/data/repositories/Auth/authRemoteDataSource.dart:119:14: Error: 'AuthProvider' is imported from both 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' and 'package:news/cubits/Auth/authCubit.dart'.
        case AuthProvider.gmail:
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/data/repositories/Auth/authRemoteDataSource.dart:128:14: Error: Not a constant expression.
        case AuthProvider.mobile:
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/data/repositories/Auth/authRemoteDataSource.dart:128:14: Error: 'AuthProvider' is imported from both 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' and 'package:news/cubits/Auth/authCubit.dart'.
        case AuthProvider.mobile:
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/data/repositories/Auth/authRemoteDataSource.dart:136:14: Error: Not a constant expression.
        case AuthProvider.fb:
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/data/repositories/Auth/authRemoteDataSource.dart:136:14: Error: 'AuthProvider' is imported from both 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' and 'package:news/cubits/Auth/authCubit.dart'.
        case AuthProvider.fb:
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/data/repositories/Auth/authRemoteDataSource.dart:144:14: Error: Not a constant expression.
        case AuthProvider.apple:
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/data/repositories/Auth/authRemoteDataSource.dart:144:14: Error: 'AuthProvider' is imported from both 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' and 'package:news/cubits/Auth/authCubit.dart'.
        case AuthProvider.apple:
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/data/repositories/Auth/authRemoteDataSource.dart:152:14: Error: Not a constant expression.
        case AuthProvider.email:
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/data/repositories/Auth/authRemoteDataSource.dart:152:14: Error: 'AuthProvider' is imported from both 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' and 'package:news/cubits/Auth/authCubit.dart'.
        case AuthProvider.email:
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/data/repositories/Auth/authRemoteDataSource.dart:114:32: Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'Map<String, dynamic>' doesn't allow null.
 - 'Map' is from 'dart:core'.
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> socialSignInUser({required AuthProvider authProvider, required BuildContext context, String? email, String? password, String? otp, String? verifiedId}) async {
                               ^
lib/data/repositories/Auth/authRemoteDataSource.dart:330:25: Error: 'AuthProvider' is imported from both 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' and 'package:news/cubits/Auth/authCubit.dart'.
    if (authProvider == AuthProvider.gmail) {
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/data/repositories/Auth/authRemoteDataSource.dart:332:32: Error: 'AuthProvider' is imported from both 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' and 'package:news/cubits/Auth/authCubit.dart'.
    } else if (authProvider == AuthProvider.fb) {
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/ui/screens/Profile/ProfileScreen.dart:268:31: Error: 'AuthProvider' is imported from both 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' and 'package:news/cubits/Auth/authCubit.dart'.
          for (int i = 0; i < AuthProvider.values.length; i++) {
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/ui/screens/Profile/ProfileScreen.dart:269:17: Error: 'AuthProvider' is imported from both 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' and 'package:news/cubits/Auth/authCubit.dart'.
            if (AuthProvider.values[i].name == context.read<AuthCubit>().getType()) {
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/ui/screens/Profile/ProfileScreen.dart:270:49: Error: 'AuthProvider' is imported from both 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' and 'package:news/cubits/Auth/authCubit.dart'.
              context.read<AuthCubit>().signOut(AuthProvider.values[i]).then((value) {
                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/ui/screens/Profile/ProfileScreen.dart:279:29: Error: 'AuthProvider' is imported from both 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' and 'package:news/cubits/Auth/authCubit.dart'.
        for (int i = 0; i < AuthProvider.values.length; i++) {
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/ui/screens/Profile/ProfileScreen.dart:280:15: Error: 'AuthProvider' is imported from both 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' and 'package:news/cubits/Auth/authCubit.dart'.
          if (AuthProvider.values[i].name == context.read<AuthCubit>().getType()) {
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/ui/screens/Profile/ProfileScreen.dart:281:47: Error: 'AuthProvider' is imported from both 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' and 'package:news/cubits/Auth/authCubit.dart'.
            context.read<AuthCubit>().signOut(AuthProvider.values[i]).then((value) {
                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception


FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Script 'c:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\groovy\flutter.groovy' line: 1350

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.
> Process 'command 'c:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 28s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           29,0s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

Hello,
I am getting this error i don't even know why, i have made flutter pub get also flutter update but nothing worked if someone can help me, i have made all updates changed changed also the version of the build code, changed the sdk everything but really nothing worked
Thanks

flutter pub get
flutter outdated
flutter update

Comment: try to track back on `socialSignInUser`'s Map which is giving null value instead of map.

Comment: How can i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

looks like you have used `AuthProvider` which is present in both of these files: `package:news/cubits/Auth/authCubit.dart` and `package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart`. You could hide it in one of the imports like this:

```dart
import 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_provider.dart' hide AuthProvider;
```

Comment: so because i have different files where i have these problems where should i put it ?

Comment: you could just rename this class, so it doesn't have conflicts.